# Why can't you use value of a field in a child class, even though it is passed in the constructor?

Tags: java

To use a simple example for my question, I have three classes, like those below:
Animal -> Bird -> Parrot

Why can't I just use the field value of `name` in the `Parrot` class, even though the value is passed in the constructor, and have to use the `getName()` method from the `Animal` class instead?

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void eat();

    public abstract void breathe();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```
public abstract class Bird extends Animal {
    public Bird(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public abstract void fly();
}
```

```
public class Parrot extends Bird{
    public Parrot(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " is eating");

    }

    @Override
    public void breathe() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " is breathing");
    }

    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " is flying");
    }
}
```

Comment: `private String name;` - because it is private. Consider making it `protected`  BTW, the `name` in `public Parrot(String name)` is not the same variable as `this.name`

Comment: Java gives you the choice - you can make a field accessible only within the class that it's defined, or you can make it accessible a bit more widely.  By writing `private`, you've explicitly said that you want the more limited accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.

Comment: In the case of `protected`, this requires that the subclass is EITHER in the same package as the superclass OR is accessing the fields of the selfsame object.  If A is a subclass of B in a different package, then an object of class A does NOT have access to the `protected` fields of a different object of class B.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What still bothers me is, when creating an object of class `Parrot`, I pass a String `name` in the constructor. Therefore in my understanding, the Parrot object has an inherited `name` field to which I assign the value during creation. When calling the `getName()` method, which field is getting returned by it? The one from class `Animal`? Which isn't really instantiated in the code? Is this the whole clue about polymorphism? Sorry, I never studied any CI, just trying to help out my relative with his problem :)